# Java OpenCV: How to convert a color image into black and white?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I have loaded the image as `gray sclae`, I know I need use threshold to binarize it. But how to do it in Java?

```
Mat imageMat = Imgcodecs.imread(picDir + "color_console.tif",
Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

//then what API?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to read this tutorial about thresholding: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html.

Documentation for `threshold` function in Java is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#threshold(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20double,%20int)). `THRESH_BINARY` and `THRESH_BINARY_INV` modes are suitable for binarization.

For example:

`Mat binarized;
threshold(imageMat, binarized, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY);`

If result will be unsatisfied, you can try `adaptivehreshold` [function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold). It performs thresholding more carefully, but it's quite computationally expensive. Documentation for Java is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#adaptiveThreshold(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20double,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double)).